# Why does std::istream_iterator<char> skip spaces?

Tags: c++, file-io

I am parsing a binary file. My code (edited for brevity) looks like:

```
std::ifstream  ifs;

...

        ifs.open(argv[i], std::ios::binary);
        if (ifs.is_open()) {

...

std::string                  header;
std::string                  data;

std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<char>(ifs), HEADER_SIZE, std::back_inserter(header));
while (!ifs.eof()) {
    if (!ifs.good()) {
        std::cerr << "Error reading message header." << std::endl;
        size = 0u;
    } else {
        data.clear();
        std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<char>(ifs), size, std::back_inserter(data));
        if (!ifs.good()) {
            std::cerr << "Error reading message data." << std::endl;
            size = 0u;
        } else {

...

    header.clear();
    std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<char>(ifs), DCP_LOG_HEADER_SIZE, std::back_inserter(header));
}
```

The binary data contains byte 0x20 as one of the bytes in a header part way through the file. The hexdump of the relevant part of the file looks like:

```
00000080  01 00 00 00 99 7a 2b 50  dd 00 04 05 00 00 00 00  |.....z+P........|
00000090  99 7c 20 50 dd 00 04 05  01 00 00 00 99 7c 21 50  |.| P.........|!P|
```

Adding debug to my code I see that the bytes are read as:

```
Header: 00 99 7a 2b 50 dd 00 04 
Data:   05 00 00 00 
Header: 00 99 7c 50 dd 00 04 05 
Error reading message data.
```

The hexdump lines up quite nicely. You can clearly see that `00 99 7c 20 50 dd 00 04` is read as `00 99 7c 50 dd 00 04` and then the subsequent byte `05` is read too.

Why is the 0x20 byte (space character) not read?

As a side question (maybe needing a separate stack overflow question), if I create a function scope variable for `std::istream_iterator<char>(ifs)` and use it to avoid the overhead of constructing such an object twice each time around the loop, I get some very odd behaviour. The first read is fine, but the second has a single null byte prepended to the read data. The third read gets two null bytes at which point the code fails. I guess that the nth read gets n-1 null bytes prepended to the read data. Why can't I re-use the object.

Also, if I use `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs)`, then even without using it as a function scope variable/object, I get null bytes pre-pended to the data.

Frankly I am very disappointed in C++ when it comes to file IO. Trying to do things in a "proper" C++ way can lead to some very awkward code, and I have read several articles which show that, without some really awkward C++ code, reading files is just quicker using basic C functions instead of using C++.

Comment: Mandatory read: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

Comment: From the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator#Notes): `"When reading characters, std::istream_iterator skips whitespace by default..."`.

Comment: If you are dealing with binary data, you can use the read function instead to read in a blob of bytes, i.e, `data.resize(size); ifs.read(data.data(), size);`

Comment: @G.M. Thanks. Could you put that as a proper answer so I can accept it, please. I have to ask, what bloody use is an iterator that skips bytes? White space matters!

Comment: @NathanOliver, that doesn't work for std:;string. I tried it. You can assign() the right number of null bytes - that works and is what I ended up doing. However I wasn't looking for a solution to use in my code with this question. I just wanted an explanation for this seemingly bizarre behaviour.

Comment: @molbdnilo I suggest you read my code more carefully. I ONLY check of EOF directly after a read. The mistake in the link you posted is that EOF is checked before reading the data. I.e. instead of doing: `while(!eof){...read...do stuff}` as per the link you posted, my code does: `read...while(!eof){...do_stuff...read more}`. This does mean I have a duplicate line of code to read the header though.